# How do I use a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a `RecyclerView` to my app, but I am having lots of difficulties. I want the `RecyclerView` to have `items` of this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtChords"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtLyrics"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I put that into its own `XML` file, and declared the `RecyclerView` in the `layout`. But I don't know how to display the `items`

Thank you!!

I searched `documentation` and tutorials, but they all do something slightly different and too complicated when comparing to what I want to do. I just want to learn the basics of `RecyclerViews` and how to use them.

I will accept examples and any link

**Please note that I am fairly new to android, and might need a simpler explanation**

Comment: looks here [recyclerview](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview#t=201705200407376294199)

Comment: This video tutorial might help you on this: https://youtu.be/UZwiKdrm768

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Recyclerview:

Recycler view is same as listview but recyclerview is added in android support lib for material design concept.

Example:

**Add dependency for recyclerview**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

**Add recyclerview in main layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Make one item layout xml file (here is ur item file)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtChords"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtLyrics"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Make one model class for each item in list.it can be any custom class.

```
public class Item {

    private String name;

    public Item(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Now most important part is to make adapter for recyclerview:**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.codexpedia.list.viewholder.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ItemArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemArrayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //All methods in this adapter are required for a bare minimum recyclerview adapter
    private int listItemLayout;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
    // Constructor of the class
    public ItemArrayAdapter(int layoutId, ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
        listItemLayout = layoutId;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    // get the size of the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size();
    }


    // specify the row layout file and click for each row
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(listItemLayout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    // load data in each row element
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        TextView item = holder.item;
        item.setText(itemList.get(listPosition).getName());
    }

    // Static inner class to initialize the views of rows
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView item;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            item = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtChords);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("onclick", "onClick " + getLayoutPosition() + " " + item.getText());
        }
    }
```

This is simple adapter with minimum requirement method.

**Now bind adapter with recyclerview**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.codexpedia.list.viewholder.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing list view with the custom adapter
        ArrayList <Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        ItemArrayAdapter itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(R.layout.list_item, itemList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);

        // Populating list items
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            itemList.add(new Item("Item " + i));
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this example will help u...
You can ask any question if u have any confusion.

You can refer this link if u want to make complex list

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Comment: What does this do??   `return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size();`

Comment: If ur itemlist is null than that line will not stop generating null pointer exception. If ur list contain 10 values that it will display 10 rows.simple terms that line returns count value for recyclerview rows

Comment: Can you explain what each of the symbols like the `?` and the `:` mean??

Comment: It is called ternary operator <condition>?<action1>:<action2>.
if itemList is null than size return 0. if itemList not null than it returns itemList.size()

Comment: ViewHolder error solved?if not than try Recyclerview.ViewHolder

Comment: I had copied the code wrong, and that's what caused that error. Very Sorry

Comment: No problem my friend...this example helps u?